# How to call function after map function done

Tags: javascript, node.js

nodejs response returning null array. 
how to return a response after map function done

```
  var follow = [];
  User.findOne(
    { _id: id },
  ).then(user => {
    user.following.map(results => {
      User.find({ _id: results.user })
        .exec()
        .then(res => {
          follow.push(res);
     });
    });
    res.json({
      status: true,
      follow // returning null array
    });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to collect the promises and use `Promise.all()` to know when they are all done:

```
User.findOne({ _id: id }).then(user => {
    let promises = user.following.map(results => {
      return User.find({ _id: results.user })
        .exec()
        .then(res => {
          return res;
     });
    });
    Promise.all(promises).then(follow => {
        res.json({
          status: true,
          follow // returning null array
        });
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.sendStatus(500);
    });
});
```

Note, there is no reason in your original code to use `.map()` if you weren't going to return anything from the `.map()` callback.  In my code, I return the promise.